# Python searching by grid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a grid, defined like this:

```
['..##.......', 
 '#...#...#..', 
 '.#..#.#..#.', 
 '..#.#...#.#', 
 '.#...##..#.', 
 '..#.##.....', 
 '.#.#.#....#',
 '.#..#.....#',
 '#.###..#...', 
 '#....#....#',
 '.#......#.#']

[2, 7, 3, 3, 8, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 3, 12, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7]
```

Where dot is a empty space and # is full. Now what I need to do is to find the biggest rectangle there is, by searching the grid. In this example it is 12 (6 - 8, all rows contain 4 dots). What I do is I save the first coordinate, go via x and see if the space is empty. If it is empty, I save x until I find that is it full. If it is full I go check bellow row of the same lenght and continue that, until I find a row that if not completly empty.

If y > 0 I also check above, so that I can get the ones overlapping aswell. My problem is, my program works fine on this array, and these 2 also:

```
['..##.......', 
 '#...#...#..', 
 '.#..#.#..#.',
 '..#.#...#.#', 
 '.#...##..#.',
 '..#.##.....']
```

Biggest is 7, gives an array = [2, 7, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3]

```
['..##.......', 
 '#...#...#..', 
 '.#..#.#..#.', 
 '..#.#...#.#', 
 '.#...##..#.', 
 '..#.##.....']
```

Biggest is 8, gives an array = [8, 7, 7, 2, 4]

But if I try something like this:

```
['.#.#.', 
 '...#.',
 '...#.',
 '####.',
 '#....',
 '#...#']
```

It returns 8 instead of 6 and gives an array = [8, 7, 7, 2, 4, 3]. What would be the problem?

This is my code

```
gen = ((x, y) for y in range(0, len(array)) for x in range(0, len(array[0])))
loc = {"x1": 0, "y1": 0, "x2": 0, "y2": 0}
temp = []
count = 0
for x, y in gen:
    if not array[y][x] == "#":
        loc["x2"] = x
        count += 1
    elif count > 1:
        i = 0
        check = False
        temp_y = y
        y += 1
        while i <= loc["x2"] and y < len(array):
            if not array[y][i] == "#":
                if i == loc["x2"]:
                    check = True
            else:
                break
            if check:
                count += i + 1
                i = 0
                loc["y2"] = y
                y += 1
                check = False
            else:
                i += 1
        y = temp_y
        if y > 0:
            i = 0
            y -= 1
            while i <= loc["x2"] and y < len(array):
                if not array[y][i] == "#":
                    if i == loc["x2"]:
                        check = True
                else:
                    break
                if check:
                    count += i + 1
                    i = 0
                    loc["y2"] = y
                    y -= 1
                    check = False
                else:
                    i += 1
        temp.append(count)
        count = 0
        loc["x1"] = x
        loc["y1"] = y
print(temp)
print(max(temp))
```

So what I do is, I find a empty space, then check below and above for the height. I am also counting how big it is (from how many empty spaces it is combined), then I save that amount inside another array (the array with numbers)

Example:

```
['...#..']
['3, 2]
```

Or a bigger one:

```
['...#...#.#',
 '....#.###.',
 '###...####']
[6 (because of the second row), 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3]
```

The problem is (see below), that it works ok, until it hits the third row, then it just loses its mind.

```
['..##.......', 
 '#...#...#..', 
 '.#..#.#..#.', 
 '..#.#...#.#', 
 '.#...##..#.', 
 '..#.##.....', 
 '.#.#.#....#',
 '.#..#.....#',
 '#.###..#...', 
 '#....#....#',
 '.#......#.#']
 [2, 7, 3, 3, 8, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 3, 12, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7]
```

Comment: If you could explain / comment your code to clarify what your algorithm is doing, I'll happily take another look at it :)

Comment: FYI - your second and third example arrays are identical. The third is a copy of the second.

Comment: What is the array of numbers you keep giving? Do you need to generate this too?

Comment: What do you mean by biggest rectangle? How do you determine what is a rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a more straight forward approach would help:

If you first build a matrix containing the number of consecutive dots going right from every position, it will be easier to combine these values to get the coordinates of the rectangle with the largest area.

```
from itertools import accumulate
def bigRect(board):
    spanSize = [ list(map(len,row.split("#"))) for row in board ]
    # print([s for ss in spanSize for s in ss if s>0]) # your array of numbers
    spans    = [ [c for s in ss for c in range(s,-1,-1)] for ss in spanSize ]
    result   = (0,0,0,0,0) # area, height, width, top, left
    for r,row in enumerate(spans):
        for c in range(len(row)):
            nextSpans = accumulate( (spanRow[c] for spanRow in spans[r:]),min)
            rectSize  = max( [(w*h,h,w) for h,w in enumerate(nextSpans,1)] )
            result    = max(result,rectSize+(r,c))
    return result
```

**Example output:**

```
B0 = ['..##.......', 
      '#...#...#..', 
      '.#..#.#..#.', 
      '..#.#...#.#', 
      '.#...##..#.', 
      '..#.##.....', 
      '.#.#.#....#',
      '.#..#.....#',
      '#.###..#...', 
      '#....#....#',
      '.#......#.#']

area,height,width,top,left = bigRect(B0)
print("Area:",area,"Size:",(height,width),"Top-Left:",(top,left))

# Area: 12 Size: (3, 4) Top-Left: (5, 6)

for row in B0[top:top+height]:
    print(row[left:left+width])
    
# ....
# ....
# ....
```

**How it works:**

The first step is to build the `spans` matrix that will contain the number of consecutive dots going right from every position.

To compute this, each line is split on the '#' character to determine the number of '.' in between them (`spanSize` has the lengths of split substrings for each line).

So '.#...##..#.' (5th line) will convert to 1,3,0,2,1. Each of these numbers represents the count of dots from the first dot's position up to the next '#'. Decrementing the numbers down to zero will produce values for individual positions with the same meaning (i.e. number of '.' up to the next '#'):

```
(1,0),(3,2,1,0),(0),(2,1,0),(1,0) --> 1,0,3,2,1,0,0,2,1,0
```

for the above example, this is what spans will contain:

```
[2, 1, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0] <-- '.#...##..#.' example
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Now, if you take each position and analyze the subsequent values in the same column, you can determine what the largest rectangle will be at that position (as the top-left corner).

This is performed by building a list of the next values going down the column but only retaining the minimum span width along the way. (this is what `accumulate(...,min)` does).

For example, from position (0,5) the values in the column are [6,3,1,3,0,...].  Accumulating the minimum value we get: [6,3,1,1,0,0,0,...].  Those are the available widths for heights 1,2,3,4... We can use the corresponding area to select the largest combination of height and width:

```
 Height  width   area 
   1       6      6
   2       3      6
   3       1      3
   4       1      4
   5       0      0
   6       ... all will be zero from there onward
```

from this we find that the largest rectangle with a top left corner of (0,5) has an area of 6 which can either be 1x6 or 2x3.

Doing this for every position you can track the largest area and return it's size and coordinates.

Comment: Great explanation! Thumbs up! Would be nice to elaborate how the "spans" work?  Thx.

Comment: Added more explanation of how the spans matrix is produced.

Answer (score 0):

Python indexing allows you to do `items[-1]` for the **last** item in the list. It looks to me that it is "wrapping around" when checking for rectangles, so as you can see the rectangle extends off the left and onto the right.

To fix this, make sure your indexes are always in the correct range (eg above 0 and less than the length)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. I already check that index should be less than y lenght.

Comment: But do you check if your indexes are negative? This is likely the issue

Comment: Just checked by printing them out, all indexes are always positive.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an easy task to find an error in your code. I find it not readable enough to review it. Instead I decided to post code which does what I think you have described as your algorithm. I hope it helps. If not, comment, ignore, or downvote, if you think it is really off-topic.

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = grid
        self.xsize = len(grid)      # must be non-zero
        self.ysize = len(grid[0])

    def is_empty(self, x, y): 
        """Is this an empty cell in the grid?"""
        if not 0 <= x < self.xsize or not 0 <= y < self.ysize:
            return False
        return self.grid[x][y] == '.' 

    def count_empty(self, x, y): 
        """count adjacent empty cells in a line starting at (x,y)."""
        cnt = 0 
        while self.is_empty(x, y): 
            cnt += 1
            y += 1
        return cnt 

g = Grid(array)

for x in range(g.xsize):
    for y in range(g.ysize):
        if not g.is_empty(x, y): 
            continue
        print(f"rectangle(s) at ({x}, {y}):")
        ry = g.ysize
        for rx1 in range(g.xsize):
            ry = min(ry, g.count_empty(x + rx1, y))
            if ry == 0:
                break
            print(f"  {rx1 + 1}*{ry}")
```

For brevity, I do not evaluate the rectangle sizes to find the max. It is trivial to add that later. It just prints all rectanlges.

The code considers each empty cell as the upper-left corner of a rectangle and not only of one rectangle, but it checks for sizes 1xN, 2xN, 3xN, etc. All coordinates are x, y = line, column.

The output looks like this:

```
rectangle(s) at (0, 0):
  1*2
rectangle(s) at (0, 1):
  1*1
  2*1
rectangle(s) at (0, 4):
  1*7
rectangle(s) at (0, 5):
  1*6
  2*3
  3*1
  4*1
... lines deleted ...
rectangle(s) at (5, 6):
  1*5
  2*4
  3*4   <--- here is what you were looking for
  4*1
  5*1
  6*1
rectangle(s) at (5, 7):
  1*4
  2*3
  3*3
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the error in your code is a challenge, because I expect your logic is flawed.
The first thing to do is simplify your code:

This:

```
    check = False
    temp_y = y
    y += 1
    while i <= loc["x2"] and y < len(array):
        if not array[y][i] == "#":
            if i == loc["x2"]:
                check = True
        else:
            break
        if check:
            count += i + 1
            i = 0
            loc["y2"] = y
            y += 1
            check = False
        else:
            i += 1
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
    temp_y = y
    y += 1
    while i <= loc["x2"] and y < len(array):
        if not array[y][i] == "#":
            if i == loc["x2"]:
                count += i + 1
                i = 0
                loc["y2"] = y
                y += 1
            else:
                i += 1
        else:
            break
```

Second, I see no reason to go up (decrementing `y`) when you're already starting out at the top left and working your way down and the right. I think your overall logic is flawed and you need to start from scratch.

Having said that, I would also start by modifying your code to keep track of the "rectangles" for each count, so that you can see if your "max" is really coming from where you think it is. I expect that you got lucky with the first two samples, and your luck didn't hold with the third sample. Again, if you track the actual rectangles in your code, it will greatly help you in debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

In case your situation is more complex than written above, you may try using [KV maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for minimizing the expressions for `#` or `.`. This approach also works for more than 2 dimensions.